# pandas rolling enabling offset even if my index is not datetime

Tags: python, pandas

For this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9])
```

df

```
       B
0.1  0.0
0.2  1.0
0.5  2.0
0.7  NaN
0.9  4.0
```

I want to perform an offset based rolling like:

```
df.rolling(0.3).sum()
```

But I got this error:

> ValueError: window must be an integer

Could anyone help me? my real case involves about 1B rows, and I needed to do groupby().rolling() in the end. The above is just an extreme simplification of my problem. Please help me. Thanks!

**The best answer** thanks to mroeschke in GitHub:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9])

In [2]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit="s")

In [3]: df.rolling("300ms").mean()
Out[3]:
                           B
1970-01-01 00:00:00.100  0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.200  0.5
1970-01-01 00:00:00.500  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.700  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.900  4.0
```

Comment: According to the docs, df.rolling() takes an integer as the first positional argument because it's the window the algo uses for calculating how many rows to take. You can't use 0.75 of a row. If your index is scaled between 0 and 1, regardless of how many rows you're actually working with, you still need an integer for the df.rolling()

Comment: @PeptideWitch, I actually want to perform rolling based on "Timestamp", but my "Timestamp" representation is only float/ integer to save time and memory. Because we have 1B such rows.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't read the docs correctly - you can indeed specify a datetime variable length window, so "300ms" should work for your case. Glad you found the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**The best answer** thanks to mroeschke in GitHub:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},index=[0.1,0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9])

In [2]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, unit="s")

In [3]: df.rolling("300ms").mean()
Out[3]:
                           B
1970-01-01 00:00:00.100  0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.200  0.5
1970-01-01 00:00:00.500  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.700  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.900  4.0
```